# Encountering IllegalArgumentException in Jboss EAP

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, wildfly

I'm miograting an app in our server, from Websphere to JBoss EAP7.
The app is working fine in the Webspehere server but when we migrate in in JBoss, we are encountering an exception upon logging in the app.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.infinispan.commons.ma  rshall.NotSerializableException
```

Here is the stacktrace of the error.

```
2019-05-28 17:17:38,161 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.infinispan.commons.ma  rshall.NotSerializableException: ph.com.crm.common.admin.ListLovListVO
2019-05-28 17:17:38,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coar  se.CoarseSessionAttributes.setAttribute(CoarseSessionAttributes.java:63)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.Distri  butableSession.setAttribute(DistributableSession.java:147)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.setAttrib  ute(HttpSessionImpl.java:169)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.crm.modules.security.LoginProcessor.t  oHomePage(LoginProcessor.java:803)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.crm.modules.security.LoginProcessor.p  erformTask(LoginProcessor.java:327)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.crm.modules.security.LoginProcessor.e  xecute(LoginProcessor.java:146)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.crm.modules.security.ActionListener.e  xecute(ActionListener.java:41)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,162 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.common.servlet.CommonServlet.performT  ask(CommonServlet.java:289)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.common.servlet.CommonServlet.doPost(C  ommonServlet.java:82)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet  .java:707)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet  .java:790)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handle  Request(ServletHandler.java:85)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecur  ityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHan  dler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityCo  ntextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl  eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,163 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformati  onAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthe  nticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl  eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidential  ityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfi  dentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechan  ismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthen  ticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,164 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiver  Handler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityCont  extAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl  eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCC  ontextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl  eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl  eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler  .handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,165 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler  .dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,166 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler  .access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,166 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler  $1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,166 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(C  onnectors.java:202)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,166 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpSe  rverExchange.java:792)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,166 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(  ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,166 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run  (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,167 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,167 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7) Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableExc  eption: ph.com.crm.common.admin.ListLovListVO
2019-05-28 17:17:38,167 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7) java.lang.Exception: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSeria  lizableException: ph.com.crm.common.admin.ListLovListVO
2019-05-28 17:17:38,168 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.crm.modules.security.LoginProcessor.t  oHomePage(LoginProcessor.java:809)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,168 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.crm.modules.security.LoginProcessor.p  erformTask(LoginProcessor.java:327)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,168 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.crm.modules.security.LoginProcessor.e  xecute(LoginProcessor.java:146)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,168 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.crm.modules.security.ActionListener.e  xecute(ActionListener.java:41)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,168 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.common.servlet.CommonServlet.performT  ask(CommonServlet.java:289)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,168 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at ph.com.common.servlet.CommonServlet.doPost(C  ommonServlet.java:82)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,169 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet  .java:707)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,169 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet  .java:790)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,169 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handle  Request(ServletHandler.java:85)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,169 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecur  ityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,169 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHan  dler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,169 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityCo  ntextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,169 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl  eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,170 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformati  onAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,170 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthe  nticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,170 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl  eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,170 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidential  ityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,170 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfi  dentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,170 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechan  ismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,170 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthen  ticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,171 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiver  Handler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,171 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityCont  extAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,171 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handl  eRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
2019-05-28 17:17:38,171 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7)         at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCC  ontextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
```

Any inputs would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JVM says this is an issue:

```
2019-05-28 17:17:38,161 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.infinispan.commons.ma  rshall.NotSerializableException: ph.com.crm.common.admin.ListLovListVO
2019-05-28 17:17:38,167 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7) Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableExc  eption: ph.com.crm.common.admin.ListLovListVO
2019-05-28 17:17:38,167 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7) java.lang.Exception: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSeria  lizableException: ph.com.crm.common.admin.ListLovListVO
```

Is that dependency from your project?  Is it part of your pom.xml?  Or was it carried over from WebSphere, assuming that it'd be part of JBOSS?

Comment: It's a class inside my project I added implements Serialization in my class specifically in ListLovListVO. And it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it by adding implements Serialization in my class specifically in ListLovListVO.